# Usage message string that optparse makes in python?

Tags: python, optparse

I use optparse module to parse the options that I make, and it automatically generates usage message to print with -h option.

How can I get the usage message as a string in a python script? I'd like to print out it when something's wrong with parsing.

Comment: Unrelated: `optparse` is deprecated since 2.7 (replaced by [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse))

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say that - had to go back to some old code where I still used optparse :)

Comment: If you can use argparse depends on the python version you need to support…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `parser.error(...)` (where `parser` is your `OptionParser` object) you'll get your usage message.

For example:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser('usage: %prog [options] target source [source ...]')
[...]

(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()

if len(args) < 2:
    parser.error('need a target and at least one source')
```

produces:

```
Usage: merge-into.py [options] target source [source ...]

merge-into.py: error: need a target and at least one source
```

Comment: It doesn't show the details of the options. Is there any way to get what `app.py -h` generates?  Thanks.

Comment: Just use `parser.print_help()` then.  Personally I think that's way too much information to give a user when they mistype something.

Answer (score 1):

How about `parser.format_help()`?